# Public class modifier for WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsformsintegration

I'm creating Windows application and Class library. Class library contains WPF control named "InsertForm.xaml"

InsertForm contains TextBox named eUserName.

I'm using the following code to show InsertForm. That's successful. But I can't access eUserName. How to set Textbox modifiers to public?

`using System.Windows.Forms.Integration`

```
ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
iform= new Extender.InsertForm();
host.Child = iform;
this.Controls.Add(host);
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Would this work?

```
<TextBox Name="eUserName" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
```